# flutter:: I have a question about how to use the app top bar

Tags: flutter, dart, appbar

This time I'm making an app top bar in flutter. I wrote code like this.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class VideoAppBar extends StatelessWidget{
  const VideoAppBar({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context){
    return SafeArea(
      child: Scaffold(
        body: WillPopScope( // <- wraps only the Scaffold body.
          child: Center(
          ),
          onWillPop: () {

            return Future(() => false);
          },
        ),
        appBar: AppBar(

          backgroundColor: Colors.white,
          title: Text('Very verse',
            style: TextStyle(
              color: Colors.black,
              fontSize: 20,
            ),),
          centerTitle: true,
          leading: IconButton(
            onPressed: () {
              Navigator.pop(context);
            },
            color: Colors.black,
            iconSize: 25,
            icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_back),

          ),

          actions: <Widget>[
            IconButton(
              icon: Icon(Icons.bookmark_outline),
              iconSize: 25,
              color: Colors.black,
              onPressed: () {
                print('GD');
              }
          ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I'd like to put this code simply as a function on several other pages.

AppBar(title:VideoAppBar);

I figured it could be done like this.

But it doesn't go back.

How should I write the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below Code hope its helpful to you

Create your regular class or your Widget like below:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(
    MyApp(),
  );
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  bool shouldPop = true;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: WillPopScope(
        onWillPop: () async {
          return shouldPop;
        },
        child: Scaffold(
          appBar: appBar(context),
          body: Center(
            child: Text('Test'),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Create another dart file like appBar.dart and declare your Appbar Widget in dart file. call your widget any file on your need

```
appBar(BuildContext context) {
  return AppBar(
    backgroundColor: Colors.white,
    title: Text(
      'Very verse',
      style: TextStyle(
        color: Colors.black,
        fontSize: 20,
      ),
    ),
    centerTitle: true,
    leading: IconButton(
      onPressed: () {
        Navigator.pop(context);
      },
      color: Colors.black,
      iconSize: 25,
      icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_back),
    ),
    actions: <Widget>[
      IconButton(
          icon: Icon(Icons.bookmark_outline),
          iconSize: 25,
          color: Colors.black,
          onPressed: () {
            print('GD');
          }),
    ],
  );
}
```

1. For [WillPopScope class](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/WillPopScope-class.html)
2. For [Scaffold class](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Scaffold-class.html)
3. For [AppBar](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/AppBar-class.html)

Your result screen -> [image]